# How to unlock account in Ethereum using a custom prompt?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, prompt, ethereum, solidity

I'm working with `Ethereum` , `javascript` , `web3.js` , `geth` , `bootstrap 3`.
the functionality is like , when the transaction happens in `blockchain` it must prompt for account unlock password.

I have accomplished below code but the problem with this is, it shows the password as text, so now I want to make a custom prompt which takes the password.

I have tried using `bootbox.js` too, but it didn't work out due to synchronization issue. i.e , before the prompt is called it gives "Account is locked" , doesn't wait for user input for password.

I want to use some interactive prompt like in "bootbox.js" to get the password and wait for user input then with that input unlock the account and then transaction to take place.

This is what I worked on

```
function unlockAccount(){
    var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
    var passPhrase = prompt("Enter the passPhrase",'');
    web3.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[0],passPhrase);

}
```

If you need any further details ask before you down vote. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (worked like a charm to me):

```js
var promptCount = 0;
    window.pw_prompt = function (options) {
      var lm = options.lm || "Password:",
        bm = options.bm || "Submit";
      if (!options.callback) {
        alert("No callback function provided! Please provide one.")
      };

      var prompt = document.createElement("div");
      prompt.className = "pw_prompt";

      var submit = function () {
        options.callback(input.value);
        document.body.removeChild(prompt);
      };

      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.textContent = lm;
      label.for = "pw_prompt_input" + (++promptCount);
      prompt.appendChild(label);

      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.id = "pw_prompt_input" + (promptCount);
      input.type = "password";
      input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) submit();
      }, false);
      prompt.appendChild(input);

      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = bm;
      button.addEventListener("click", submit, false);
      prompt.appendChild(button);

      document.body.appendChild(prompt);
      document.getElementById(input.id).focus()
    };

pw_prompt({        
        lm: 'Enter Password to load your identity',
        bm: 'Load',
        callback: function (password) {     
          web3.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[0], password);
      }});
```

```css
.pw_prompt {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        padding: 15px;
        /* width: 263px; */
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: darkgrey;
    }
.pw_prompt label {
  display:block; 
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.pw_prompt input {
  width:300px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , i need to review it or somebody else.
I tackled it using Promise and deferred technique.